# Getting a Syntax/Parse error when using jQuery in Velocity

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript>
(function($, win) {
function mySettingsInitJS () {  

    var self = this;
    var opts = {
        'params' : "userId=" + userId;
    }; 
    self.init = function() {
        self.initUnlinkAction();
    };
    self.initbtnAction = function() {
        $('#Btn').click(self.btnAction);
    };

    self.btnAction = function(e) {
        if(e) { e.preventDefault(); }
        jQuery.post(
        'http://abc/rest/PostRequest', 
        opts.params, function(data) {
        alert('This worked!');
        }, "json");                         
    };

}
function win.MyFilesSettingsInitJS = new MyFilesSettingsInitJS();
}(jQuery, window));
</script>
```

I have this this script in a velocity template page and a Btn also in it. Which is basically a fancy Link. I am also sure the rest API on the server side is working fine. But somehow my java script function is not called. Could some one please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot quotes here:

```
'http://abc/rest/PostRequest'
```

It becomes pretty obvious with good syntax highlighting. Plus if you use [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or similar it will find most problems, as well as the console when debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL value needs to be a string...add quotes to it

Comment: Yep I tried that, the problem still persists. The thing is i'm getting the url using a Velocity variable like #set($apiURL = ..). I'm not using it directly. When i check the debugger it seems to have picked up the right url.

Comment: is request being made cross domain?  If not, inspect request itself in browser console...paste returned JSON into jsonlint.com to make sure it is valid. If is cross domain you need to use jsonp and server needs to respond with jsonp

Answer (score 0):

You should use some developer tools available in the browser. Most browsers have at least an error console that would display any JS errors. For example, this code has several syntax errors:

1. In `var opts = { 'params' : "userId=" + userId; };` it is illegal to end a line with `;` when you're defining an object literal (a.k.a. map or dictionary).
2. Again at this line, where is `userId` defined? It is a bad practice to have global variables, so if `userId` is a global variable defined in another script, you should refactor the code
3. `function win.MyFilesSettingsInitJS = new MyFilesSettingsInitJS();` is illegal, since you're adding a property to an object, you're not declaring a function or a variable. Just use `win.MyFilesSettingsInitJS = new MyFilesSettingsInitJS();`
4. Actually, that might be wrong as well, since above you defined `mySettingsInitJS`, not `MyFilesSettingsInitJS` (but that function could actually be defined somewhere else, I don't have the whole code)